# pip install : Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement curses

Tags: python, module, pip, curses

I have an issue to install modules in python, I am trying to `pip install curses`, but i get below error.

```
C:\Users\Manu>pip install curses
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement curses (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for curses
```

Answer (score 3):

The error simply states that the package you are trying to install is not found.

The curses library in windows can be installed by

```
pip install windows-curses
```